# Ubuntu 18.04 - Mounting additional HD & FSTAB errors

Tags: fstab

I try to mount a 2nd HD using this method:

Adding a line in`fstab`:

```
UUID=3edefcc8-04fb-449b-9e72-9bda7e443f65 /home/guy/newHD ext4 defaults x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Mount shows and works **OK** (as far as I know at this point), but an error pops after mounting

```
$ sudo mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 14 -- ignored
```

Line 14 is the relevant line.

Tries to solve:

1. add `comments=x-gvfs-show` - did not solve.
2. adding/ removing `,` before after `x-gvfs-show` - did not solve
3. deleting `x-gvfs-show` from line 14- stopped showing that error message.

What is the right syntax?

Adding pic from `Disks` showing that that specific parameter is relevant and needed

[image]

Comment: White space is a delimiter, so you've got too many fields. If you have multiple parameters that need to go in the same field, use a comm "," to seperate them...  I've not used " x-gvfs-show" so don't know what that is, nor where it belongs sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as noted in a comment- @guiverc, white-space is also a delimiter, and so is a comma...

so the right answer ( or- my mistake ) is

```
UUID=3edefcc8-04fb-449b-9e72-9bda7e443f65 /home/guy/newHD ext4 defaults,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

so - use comma, without white-space